# Showing exitence of a path in Graph Theory

Tags: graph-theory

> If $P$ and $Q$ are paths in a connected graph that have no vertices in common, then there exist vertices $u$ and $v$ and a path $P′$ such that $u$ is on $P$, $v$ is on $Q$, $P′$ is a $u–v$ path, and no internal vertex of $P′$ is on either of the paths $P$ or $Q$.

Let $P = (u_1, \ldots u_n)$ and $Q = (v_1, \ldots, v_n)$. Then, let $P' = (u_j, u_{n + 1}, v_{n + 1}, v_j)$ where $1 \le j \le n$.

Would that prove the claim?

Comment: What is $u_{n+1}$ and $v_{n+1}$?

Comment: They are vertices that are not on $p$ or $Q$.

Comment: What makes you think they exist?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: consider $T=(w_1,\dots,w_m)$ a path of minimal length so that $w_1$ lies in  $P$ and $w_m$  lies in $Q$. Using minimality, can you show that this path satisfies the desired property?

Comment: Can you, please, state the definition of minimality since I didn't get that far yet ?

Comment: @Clojure, first recall the length of a path is defined as the number of edges in the path. That is, the path $(w_1,w_2)$ has length $1$, and in general the path $(w_1,\dots,w_m)$ has length $m-1$. To say that $T$ is a path of minimal length satisfying a given property means that no path with shorter length also satisfies that property. In the hint, this means that if $T' = (w_1',\dots,w_k')$ is a path with $w_1'\in P$ and $w_k' \in Q$, then $m\leq k$.  The idea is to show that if $w_j \in P$ or $w_j \in Q$ for $1<j<m$, then $T$ does not satisfy this condition.